How to handle multiple color palettes?
I'm a newbie here and in programming overall.
I am working on a project that resembles a pixel art editor using React + Redux and Canvas.
I want to give the user the option to create and use their own color palettes that will be global for every drawing. Users can also create aliases for colors, e.g., "#4682b4" can be named "steel blue." Additionally, I want to create a "default" color palette for each drawing. When a user uses a color from a palette, I add that color to the "default" palette. But I'm struggling with the implementation.

How do I handle switching between palettes?

How do I handle colors with the same hex but different names/palettes?

How do I handle replacing a color from one palette with a color in another palette?

How do I handle replacing a color in a palette that was used in dozens of drawings?


Perhaps I am overcomplicating things... How can I implement my idea or simplify it without discarding the idea of custom palettes?

Here is what I tried:
I created a ColorPalette component that renders list of colors in this way
// ColorPalette component

return(
<div className="some-wrapper">
{colors.map(
  (item: Partial<Palette>, colorIndex: number) => (
    <ColorItem
      index={colorIndex}
      key={item.hex}
      color={item as Color}
      onDelete={() => onDeleteColorFromPalette(index, item)}
      onUpdate={updateColorInPalette}
      onSelect={onSelectActive}
      active={activeColor === item.hex}
    />
))}
</div>
)

When the user selects the drawing palette I use the palette from EditorState, but when the user switches to their own palette I use UserPalettesState. Because of the different interfaces, I have to render the same component but with different event handlers.
// EditorPalette component

const EDITOR_PALETTE = 'editor';
const [paletteVariant, setVariant] = useState(EDITOR_PALETTE);

const userPalette = 
    paletteVariant === EDITOR_PALETTE ? 
    null : 
    userPalettes.find(({ id }) => id === Number(paletteVariant));

return (
<div className="some-wrapper"> 
  <Select
    value={paletteVariant}
    onChange={(e) => setVariant(e.target.value)}
  >
    <MenuItem value={EDITOR_PALETTE}>
      {i18n.projectsPalette}
    </MenuItem>
    {userPalettes.map((palette) => (
      <MenuItem value={palette.id} key={palette.id}>
        {palette.name}
      </MenuItem>
     ))}
  </Select>
  {paletteVariant === EDITOR_PALETTE? (
    <ColorPalette
      palette={editorPalette}
      onAddColorToPalette={addColorToEditor}
      onDeleteColorFromPalette={deleteColorFromEditor}
      onChangeColorInPalette={changeColorInEditor}
      onSelectActive={setActiveEditorColor}
      activeColor={editorPalette.active}
    />
  ) : (
    <ColorPalette
      palette={userPalette}
      onSelectActive={setActiveEditorColor}
      activeColor={editorPalette.active}
     // other handlers doesn't work right now :(
    />
  )}
</div>
);

// general interfaces
interface Palette {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  colors: Color[],
}

interface Color {
  id: number,
  hex: string,
  name: string,
}

// state of canvas
type EditorState = {
  instrument: Instrument;
  palette: {
    active: string; // this is hex of the current active color
    colors: Color[]; // this is list of colors from default palette
  };
  // ...other props
};

// state of user defined palettes
type UserPalettesState = {
  data: Palette[];
  loading: boolean;
}

But approach with two different states proved to be complicated. I also tried turn around interfaces to get a single list of colors. Like this
interface Color {
  id: number,
  hex: string,
  name: string,
  paletteId: number,
  paletteName: string,
  isActive: boolean,
}

But it doesn't solve an issue with duplicated hex values in different palettes. And somehow make switching between palettes even harder. What should I do?
